# Fundamental Energy Equation comparison confusion

Tags: thermodynamics

I was listening to an introductory lecture today about the fundamental energy equation given below.

$$d U=T d S-P d V+\sum_{j=1}^{M} \mu_{j} d N_{j}$$

My lecturer mentioned that through simple manipulation, the following useful form of the fundamental entropy equation can be achieved. This was not too difficult - simple rearrangement of a subject.

$$d S=\left(\frac{1}{T}\right) d U+\left(\frac{P}{T}\right) d V-\sum_{j=1}^{M} \frac{\mu_{j}}{T} d N_{j}$$

However, he then stated the following:

> Comparing both the equations above can give the following useful results:

$$\frac{1}{T}=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V, N}, \frac{P}{T}=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U, N}, \frac{\mu_{j}}{T}=-\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N_{j}}\right)_{U, V, N_{i≠j}}$$

I studied these differential results previously and I know that these results are all valid, but I can't understand how he compared the two equation above.

He made no mention of how he *compared* the two equations, he simply just mentioned the results and moved on.

How did he achieve the useful results by comparing both equations?

Comment: By solving for $dS$ in the first equation, and then noting $dS=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V, N}dU+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U, N}dV+ \sum^{M}_{j=1}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N_{j}}\right)_{U, V,...,N_{M}}dN_{j}$. You can choose either the energy or entropy representation.

Answer (score 1):

In multivariable calculus, if we know that

$$
S = S(U,V,N_1,N_2,\dots,N_n)
$$

then we can write the total derivative of $S$ as

$$
\text{d}S = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)\text{d}U + 
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)\text{d}V
+
\sum_{j=1}^n
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N_j}\right)\text{d}N_j.
$$

In thermodynamics, it is convenient to add subscripts to be extra clear about which quantities are being held constant in each partial derivative, giving the expression 
$$
\text{d}S = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V,N_j}\text{d}U + 
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U,N_j}\text{d}V
+
\sum_{j=1}^n
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N_j}\right)_{U,V,N_{i\neq j}}\text{d}N_j.
$$

Comparing this to your second equation demonstrates your final equation.

Comment: I would say that the subscripts used in thermodynamics are a necessity, due to the misuse of the symbols common in thermodynamics: the reason for adding which quantities are kept constant is connected to the fact that the same symbol (say $S$) is used to indicate different functions.. For example $S(U,V,N)$ and $S(T,V,N)=S(U(T,V,N),V,N)$ which which are actualy different functions of their arguments.

Comment: In the context of this answer, the subscripts aren't strictly necessary because it is possible to clarify which other properties are held constant when evaluating partial derivatives by identifying the independent and dependent variables, as I did in my first equation. The subscripts are *convenient* because the third equation can stand alone while the second equation is only meaningful when the first is also provided for context.  In other contexts (where partials corresponding to multiple sets of independent variables are present together) I agree that subscripts are necessary.